# Consulta muestra datos diferentes cada vez que la ejecuto Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT pr_production_units_details.id AS idProductionUnit, pr_production_units_details.production_units_detail AS productionUnit,
IF(pr_varieties.variety IS NULL, 'SIN SEMBRAR O ERR', pr_varieties.variety) AS variety
FROM pr_production_units_details
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MAX(sw_sowing.id) AS ids, sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail,  sw_sowing.id_variety
FROM sw_sowing
WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = 1
AND YEARWEEK(sw_sowing.date) <= 201741
GROUP BY sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail, id_variety
ORDER BY ids DESC
) AS sw ON pr_production_units_details.id = sw.id_production_unit_detail
INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON sw.id_variety = pr_varieties.id
WHERE pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail = 1
AND pr_production_units_details.status = 100
AND pr_production_units_details.id_tenant = 1
GROUP BY pr_production_units_details.id
```

que me trae el siguiente resultado:

```
------------------------------------------------
  idProductionUnit | productionUnit |  variety
------------------------------------------------
        1          |        1       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
        2          |        2       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
        3          |        3       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
```

El resultado anterior esta bien , pero cada vez que la ejecuto la columna variety cambia sus valores, es decir,

```
------------------------------------------------
  idProductionUnit | productionUnit |  variety
------------------------------------------------
        1          |        1       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
        2          |        2       |   BLUE 
------------------------------------------------
        3          |        3       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
```

o puede salir también así;

```
------------------------------------------------
  idProductionUnit | productionUnit |  variety
------------------------------------------------
        1          |        1       |   BLUE 
------------------------------------------------
        2          |        2       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
        3          |        3       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
```

No se si tenga que ver por el ORDER BY o el GROUP BY pero no he entendido porque me muestra diferentes datos.

Comment: Puedes poner como están estructuradas las tablas para verlo mejor

Comment: Agrega la estructura de las tablas y sus relaciones, para entenderlo mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude solucionar el inconveniente, tengo entendido que es por el GROUP BY que tengo en LEFT JOIN así que cambie la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT  pr_production_units_details.id AS idProductionUnit, pr_production_units_details.production_units_detail AS  productionUnit, pr_varieties.variety
FROM (SELECT MAX(sw_sowing.id) AS id
            FROM sw_sowing
            WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
            AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = 1
            AND YEARWEEK(sw_sowing.date) <= 201741
            GROUP BY  sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
)AS sw
INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
INNER JOIN pr_production_units_details ON pr_production_units_details.id = sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = sw_sowing.id_variety
WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0 
AND sw_sowing.id_tenant =1
AND pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail = 13
GROUP BY pr_production_units_details.id, variety
```

Sólo me falta la condición para saber si variety esta NULL para colocar 'SIN SEMBRAR' pero eso lo hago internamente.